# Cannot use getDefaultMiddleware/apiSlice with redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am implementing `RTK Query` for which I need to edit my `store`. Currently, my store setup looks liket his

```
import {configureStore, combineReducers} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {useDispatch, useSelector, TypedUseSelectorHook} from 'react-redux';
import {apiSlice} from './api';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage'
import {
    persistReducer,
    persistStore,
} from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {getPersistConfig} from 'redux-deep-persist';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    settings: settingsReducer,
    user: userReducer
})

const config = getPersistConfig({
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['user.name', 'settings.color'],
    rootReducer
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(config, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: [thunk]
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

Now, when using `RTK Query` I need to alter the following lines

```
export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    settings: settingsReducer,
    user: userReducer,
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
})

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware)
});
```

I have to (?) replace `middleware: [thunk]` with `middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware)`. However, when I do this, I get the following error

> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `register`. Value:
> function register(key). Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:
> Object { type: "persist/PERSIST", register: register(key), rehydrate: rehydrate(key, payload, err)}

> (See https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants)
> (To allow non-serializable values see: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)

Is there any way to get `[thunk]` and `getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware)` into the `middleware`, or is it not possible to use `RTK Query` with my setup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist

Comment: @LinDu I am not sure... How would the `middleware` prop in `configureStore` then look like?

Comment: The issue is "A non-serializable value was detected in an action", why are you trying to get the `redux-thunk` middleware? The problem is X, you are asking Y?

Comment: @LinDu I am unsure how to understand the issue and how that is related to `middleware: [thunk]`. To be honest, I am not even 100% sure what  `middleware: [thunk]` does. What I can confirm is that when I remove it, the issue arises and now I am unsure how to add `RTK Query` tackel the `non-serializable value` issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your previous setup removed all the middleware that Redux Toolkit usually includes to ensure that you are not putting things into the store that don't belong into the store. Now you go to the recommended setup, so those tests run and you are getting error messages.

Your warnings here are about redux-persist that needs additional configuration because it bends these rules quite a lot.

You can find help on that [here in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist):

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(apiSlice.middleware),
});
```